# Electrostatics - Charging with friction

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge

We know that rubbing two objects, let's say silk and glass with each other one gains electron and another loses electron. In this condition glass rod loses electron and silk gains them. Now there is less number of electron in glass rod.

**Now my question is how glass rod comes to normal condition i.e: Coming to initial state as it was which means re-gaining of electron or any other means that I don't wanted to ask?**

**Similar question:** [Solve my confusion about electrons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105288/)

But I didn't understand what he said or explained.
Hope anyone understands my question.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the glass rod will regain its lost electrons due to leakage from earth. Conversely the silk will lose its gained electrons due to leakage to earth. The process is slow because these are slow moving charges.